# Validation of value from two column of a sheet with insertion of value in another column of different sheet of an excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Sheet 1, say column A and whatever be the value going to be inserted in a particular cell for this column it should be validated from Column B and Column C of Sheet 2. If the value entered in the column A of sheet 1 matches with Column B and C of sheet 2, accept that value in the cell of sheet 1 else throw an error.

Sheet 2

```
Column B  Column C
234        657
456        378
678        451
```

Sheet 1 :

```
Column A

678 - this should be allowed but when i should insert
123 - this should throw an error as this value is not present in either column of Sheet 2.
```

I have tried using Range name to create the drop down list in another sheet based on the value source and then using Data Validation dialog and select List from the Allow drop down list but this is only working for one column value not for the value present in both the column B and C.

Anyone having any idea on how to frame this validation in formula

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to your second question:

*I want to use Concatenate inside this formula.Say, I want to concatenate the value of two columns in the current sheet and then result should be compared with the concatenation of two column value in another sheet. E.g - The entered value in Column W and X in current sheet should be compared with the existing value in column Y and column Z of another sheet. I have tried using the formula COUNTIF(Sheet2!CONCAT($W$2,$X$2:$Y$2,$Z$2),A2)>0 and some different alteration but no luck.*

Let's assume we have two sheets.

**Sheet1** -> columns W&X -> this is where we will enter our data and create Data Validation.

**Sheet2** -> columns Y&Z -> contains values against which we want to validate our input. In my example, I populated cells Y1:Z3 with the following values:

[image: Sheet2]

Now, going back to **Sheet1**, our goal is to be able to check a combination of column W & X in order to validate if an input should be accepted. For example:

[image: Sheet1]

In order to achieve that, you need to click on Sheet1 cell X1, go to Data Validation > Custom > enter the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(W1&X1,Sheet2!$Y$1:$Y$3&Sheet2!$Z$1:$Z$3,0)))
```

The formula will combine what you're entering into cell X1 with a value of cell W1 and check if such combination already exists in Sheet2, cells Y1:Z3.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @Justyna MK.It works like a charm.

Comment: Glad it helped! Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using COUNTIF in your Data Validation.

Assuming that your values are inserted into cells B1:C3, click on cell A1 > Data > Data Validation > Allow: Custom > Formula: =COUNTIF($B$1:$C$3,$A1)>0

After applying this validation, enter a value of 1 into cell A1 (it should return an error), while 657 should be accepted. Now you can copy & paste this validation into other cells in column A.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not understand the above explanation fully but just to inform , as this validation needs to be done in two sheet of same workbook.So, this should validate the value inserted in cell of first sheet.                                                                                                                Although i tried COUNTIF using the formula **"COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2)>0"** in Sheet 1, but again it's taking the single column value from Sheet 2 and it is validating for single column value present in Sheet 2.

Comment: Hi Trips, if your values are in Sheet2, cells B1:C3, and you want to enter your data into Sheet1, cell A1, then your Data Validation formula should be:
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$1:$C$3,$A1)>0

Comment: Hi Justyna, Actually i was giving wrong range in the above formula which i have mentioned.I had modified to "COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:B,A2)>0"and its working fine. thank you for your reply..

Comment: Need your suggestion here.I want to use *Concatenate* inside this formula.Say, I want to concatenate the value of two columns in the current sheet and then result should be compared with the concatenation of two column value in another sheet.
E.g - The entered value in Column W and X in current sheet should be compared with the existing value in column Y and column Z of another sheet.     I have tried using the formula COUNTIF(Sheet2!CONCAT($W$2,$X$2:$Y$2,$Z$2),A2)>0 and some different alteration  but no luck.

Comment: Hey Trips, sorry for the delay - I have been off for a few weeks. Do you still need an answer to your last question?

Comment: thanks @Justyna MK.Yes, i m still trying to find an answer via this way.just to make it more easier, I have an excel comprise of two sheet : Sheet1 and Sheet2 **Sheet 1 ColumnA ColumnB fieldCombination **123 XYZ 123XYZ This field combination I am trying to validate in sheet 2 of same excel **Sheet 2 ColumnC Column D fieldCombination** 123 XYZ 123XYZ Without fieldCombination(single column value) I can able to validate using our above formula =COUNTIF(Sheet2!C:D,E2)>0 where E refers to the column in Sheet 1 where I want to apply the validation. But I want to validate with fieldCombination.

Comment: Hey, I will add a separate answer to this topic as it will be easier to format it. I will follow your first example (columns W-X and Y-Z) as it was easier for me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved using the formula COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:B,A2)>0, where Sheet 2 refers to the sheet from which the value has to be verfied and A:B is a range of  two column in which value has been mentioned and A2 is the cell where you want to do the validation

thanks.